# form_radio en CodeIgniter no funciona

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo un sistema que esta hecho en Code Igniter 2, tengo un formulario que contiene un form_radio que guarda el parámetro si un empleado utiliza factura o no, este es el codigo

```
 <div>
   <label for="factura" class="forma" >Factura de comisionista:</label>
    <?php echo form_radio('factura', '1', FALSE, 'class="factura"'); ?>S&iacute; 
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <?php echo form_radio('factura', '0', FALSE, 'class="factura"');?>No
 </div>
```

Esto es en la vista principal, donde se guardan los datos del empleado por primera vez, ahora el problema me resulta en la vista donde quiero actualizar la información, justamente al momento de querer actualizar ese form_radio, si yo actualizo y guardo el cambio, el cambio realmente nunca se aplica, el form_radio queda igual.

el código no lo hice yo, sin embargo siento que la forma en como se hizo la instrucción no esta bien empleada

¿hay alguna forma de poder actualizar correctamente ese parametro del form_radio y que se guarde?

anexo imagen

[image: codigo que toma el valor del form_radio del primer formulario para actualizar]

Answer (score 0):

Para este tipo de cosas yo uso esta estructura:

```
<?php

    $registro['factura'] = 1; // $comisionista->factura;

    $field = array(
      'name' => 'factura',
      'label'=>'Factura de comisionista:',
      'default' => 0,
      'values' => array( 1 => 'SI', 0 => 'NO'),
    );

    echo form_label( $field['label'], $field['name']);
    foreach ($field['values'] as $option_value => $option_label) :
      echo form_radio(
        $field['name'],
        $option_value,
        (
          set_value($field['name'], (
            (isset($registro[$field['name']]) && $registro[$field['name']] != NULL) ?
            $registro[$field['name']] :
            $field['default'])
          ) == $option_value)
      );
      echo $option_label."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    endforeach;
?>
```

En el array `$registro` vienen los valores del registro (lo que está en la base de datos).

En el array `$field` defino:

- nombre,
- etiqueta,
- valor default
- el array de los valores posibles: `valor => etiqueta`.

Luego de imprimir la etiqueta global del campo, recorro los valores posibles (las opciones del campo) e imprimo el `form_radio` con las siguientes opciones:

```
form_radio('nombre', 'valor', 'true si está seleccionado')
```

Es el "si está seleccionado" la parte mas enroscada, para esto usamos `set_value` que tiene la forma :

```
set_value("nombre", "defult")
```

Si el campo "nombre" ya tiene valor (luego de un `form_validation->run()`) se asigna ese valor, si no es así en el segundo parámetro le indicamos el default que es en caso de que sea la primer vez que accedes al formulario, aquí lo que hacemos, para saber que valor "default" usar, es verificar que "name", el nombre del campo, exista entre los valores de `$registro` si es así usamos ese valor, si no existe usamos el default del campo definido en `$field`.

Con lo cual setvalue tendrá uno de estos valores :

1. el valor seteado desde el último post (si falla `form_validation->run()`)
2. el valor guardado en `$registro`
3. el valor default para este campo definido en `$field`

Este último valor es el que comparamos con el valor que tendría esta opción en particular, si coinciden el radio irá `checked` si no coinciden se imprime sin `checked`.